# Upside down text consitent across browsers

Tags: html, css, cross-browser

I've been looking at inverting a single character in a line of text using CSS rather than an image but everytime I get the css to work correctly and inline in one browser, the letter is usually 1/2px out of line in others (this goes for Firedfox 45, Edge and chrome).

So far I've got

```
<style>
  @import url(https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Droid+Serif);
  * {font-family:"droid serif"}
  div {position:relative; float:left; display:inline-block }
  div h1 { margin:0; font-size:3em; position:relative; }
  div h1.invert { float:left; transform: scale(-1,-1); 
  /* Also tried 
  div h1.invert { float:left; transform:rotate(180deg);}
  */
</style>

<div>
  <div>
    <h1>THI</h1>
  </div>
  <div>
    <h1 class="invert">S</h1>
  </div>
</div>
```

Obligatory fiddle.... https://jsfiddle.net/1q9jbuf8/

Comment: I was excitedly going to recommend you use Unicode upside down characters, but unfortunately the upside down S looks the same as the right side up version. :-(

Comment: You could mirror it, though: Ƨ

Comment: Sorry, forgot to mention i did try the unicode method but only edge and chrome changed had the correct font.. firefox just had the default font shown (because that would have been too easy naturally </sarcasm>)

Oh and @ralph.m mirroring would be fine, if I just wanted to mirror it on the horizontal plane but I wanted it to mirror on the vertical plane too

Comment: I've updated my answer with a fiddle. You can imagine that things would change dramatically if the font family changes (as in most browsers on different OSes). Perhaps telling us what you need to do in the end provides a different solution that works.

Comment: Basically the aim was to invert a V to replicate an A, it's for a company name and I was trying to replace the image they had before with something more responsive than the image they had before. 

Thinking about it. I might just push it in as an SVG as i'm getting visions of working with ie 6 all over again.

Comment: Since it looks like there's currently no solution to this that doesn't require a bunch of hacks or separate css sheets for different browsers (what is this 2006?) so i've gone and done it as an SVG in the end. 

I'll keep it open for a little while to see if anyone else has any ideas, if not @SideriteZackwehdex i'll accept your answer and close this.

Comment: I think if you do it with SVG it will be cross browser and much more stable than any direct font manipulation. I mean, you control the input and the output, as opposed to whatever the browser decides to render as text.

Comment: Even then you've still got to convert to paths rather than embed the gliphs (because again... that would easy), it was more for SEO type stuff but I can always add the same info as as a screen reader property and leave it at that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is not the actual letter, but the spacing inside the font. You can check this by using `$('.invert')[0].getClientRects()[0]` and then applying your transform and checking again. If anything, the only thing that changes is the horizontal position.

I see no way of solving this without drawing the text on a canvas, determining the actual rectangle with pixels, then rotating only that. Maybe someone else has a better solution, but the only reasonable one should be individual fixes for fonts and sizes you can control (like adding `position:relative; top: 1px;`)

I played around with it for a while: https://jsfiddle.net/v06j5hz0/6/

There I simplified the inverted model (BTW: inverted means `rotateX`, not rotate) and I am displaying the actual rectangle sizes, positions and so on. Unfortunately, other than being aware of the actual font and size and updating the `transform-origin` point, I have no solution.

Comment: Setting this as the answer, unless something changes with regards to browsers and the centre point for rotation/mirroring then generating an svg is currently the only way that works in a constant manor (without creating browser specific rules or waiting for a fix that may never come. As well as still not fix earlier browsers anyway).